# How to push to a different branch with hg-git?

Tags: hg-git

While I was working on my Git repository clone, the remote content changed:

```
$ hg push
...
abort: refs/heads/master changed on the server, please pull and merge
 before pushing
```

Instead of merging, I want to push commits from my local copy to different remote branch. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it myself.

```
hg bookmark fixes             # copy content to new git branch 'fixes'
hg bookmark --delete master   # remove old master branch, to avoid abort error
hg push
```

It is way easier that moving commits to a different branch in `git` itself.